# How to access images in library project from main project in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have created one library project in iphone and my images folder is present in my main project. How do i access that images?

Comment: can you ask question more briefly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the app's resources using `NSBundle`'s methods:

```
NSString *imageFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the resources from NSBundle class.

If your resources is in current application executable, at that time you need to use "[NSBundle mainBundle]".

If you have main bundles in your application, we have a property in NSBundle called "allbundles". It will returns an array of all the application’s non-framework bundles.So that, you can call your resources from any of the bundle.

I think this may useful for you.